# How to create a Entity Ruler pattern that includes dot and hyphen?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am trying to include brazilian CPF as entity on my NER app using spacy. The current code is the follow:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")

text = "João mora na Bahia, 22/11/1985, seu cpf é 111.222.333-11"
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [
    {"label": "CPF", "pattern": [{"SHAPE": "ddd.ddd.ddd-dd"}]},
]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
doc = nlp(text)

#extract entities
for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```

The result was only:

```
João PER
Bahia LOC
```

I tried using regex too:

```
{"label": "CPF", "pattern": [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}$"}}]},
```

But not worked too

How can I fix that to retrieve CPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for token spacings, the brazilian tokenizer split cpf in two parts:

```
token_spacings = [token.text_with_ws for token in doc]
```

Result:

```
['João ', 'mora ', 'na ', 'Bahia', ', ', '22/11/1985', ', ', 'seu ', 'cpf ', 'é ', '111.222.', '333-11']
```

So i think you may try this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")

text = "João mora na Bahia, 22/11/1985, seu cpf é 111.222.333-11"
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [
    {"label": "CPF", "pattern": [
            {"SHAPE": "ddd.ddd."},
            {"SHAPE": "ddd-dd"},
    ]},
]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
doc = nlp(text)

#extract entities
for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```